# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.bindActionCreators) is not a functin

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm playing around with redux, I'm and started getting this error, can't resolve it, I was hoping it has any meaning, but can't seem to find any information.. Can anyone explain the reason this may show? Thanks..

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'react-redux';
import  { searchForBeers } from '../../actions/index';


class SearchBar extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { term: ''}

    this.onFieldChange = this.onFieldChange.bind(this);
    this.onClickSearch = this.onClickSearch.bind(this);
  }

  onFieldChange(event) {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value })

    console.log(this.state)
  }

  onClickSearch() {
    console.log(this.state)

    this.props.searchForBeers(this.state.term)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-lg-6" style={{top:20 , width:'70%'}}>
           <div className="input-group">
         <span className="input-group-btn">
           <button onClick={this.onClickSearch} className="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
         </span>
         <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." onChange={this.onFieldChange} />
       </div>
       </div>
    )
  }

}

//Container functions

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ searchForBeers }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Package json:

```
{
  "name": "redux-simple-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple starter package for Redux with React and Babel support",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter.git",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.13.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.4",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.0",
    "redux-simple-promise": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't doubt the error message. *Which* expression is not returning the expected function? Once that is determined it's just a matter of working backward to find out *why*.

Comment: This is throwing on the application load, so I have no way of really understanding where does it get stuck.. I've console logged at the action and reducer, all values look currect.. This is my first day with react and redux, so I was expecting the error to have some meaning..

Comment: The error indicates that `_errorRedux.bindActionCreators` does *not* return a function-object. I suspect it evaluates to undefined: _errorRedux does not evaluate to the object it is believed to evaluate to, or there is no bindActionsCreators property (often caused by a typo, sometimes an API mismatch). This general class of error is easy to reproduce in a console: `(0, undefined)("can't call undefined as a function")`, eg.

Comment: First clue is `import { bindActionCreators } from 'react-redux';`. It probably does not exist. Make sure your version of `react-redux` and the version whatever guide you're following uses are in sync.

Comment: @ivarni yes you are right! I should have use "import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';" and this was a breaking change of a redux version... Thank you so much! Make it an official answer so I can approve it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's the [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) module that provides the `bindActionCreators` function so the correct way to import it would be

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
```

instead of importing it from `react-redux`.

There is a page with examples in the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) over at their API documentation site.

The error you're seeing simply looks funky because of the way babel transpiles ES2015 modules but it's not actually React or Redux that's throwing it.

Comment: THANK YOU. As a self-proclaimed React vet, this took me way too long to figure out why it was breaking in a new project of mine.

Comment: As another self-proclaimed React vet, I am astonished by your insights! Thanks!